# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'VITE_DEFAULT_LOCALE')

Tags: vue.js, vue-i18n

I cant undestand why its not working. becaause my index.js is not connect generaly

.env
`VITE_DEFAULT_LOCALE=en VITE_SECOND_LOCALE=uz VITE_FALLBACK_LOCALE=ru VITE_BASE_URL=/`

i18n/index.js
`import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";`
`export default createI18n({ locale: import.meta.env.VITE_DEFAULT_LOCALE, fallbackLocale: import.meta.env.VITE_FALLBACK_LOCALE, legacy: false, messages //just object with transltion words })`

i just see guide how connect i18n in my application

Comment: "my index.js is not connect generaly" - what is the meaning of this? It's unknown what's your setup and whether you use Vite at all. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Try using literal constants instead of environment variables for the default and fallback locales.